# Is it possible to restore Gitlab-CE from files from previous installation?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, restore, gitlab-ce

recently I was forced to migrate from VPS hosting I had. I was away from home when I was asked to perform backups before the end of lease, so I had no time to backup all of the data in a way that backup should've been performed and that left me with all of my VPS data packed into a single .tar.gz.

Almost everything went smooth, the last thing that gives me nightmares is restoring my previous Gitlab-CE data.

This time I went with the dockerized version of Gitlab-CE. (gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.4.0-ce.0)

To be sure that I am not using wrong version during this process, I extracted which version I had installed from one of license files found in the backup.

I have confirmed that this image works without my data being mounted to volumes, but whenever I've tried to mount volumes recovered from backup:

> /home/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
>
> /home/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
>
> /home/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab

I was stuck with a fatal error regarding postgres db:

> [execute] psql: FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
>
> DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
>
> HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.

I have tried setting ENV variables **LANG, LANGUAGE, LC_ALL** to different values without any luck.

I was not able to find solution on the internet so far, I wish I could've made a backup properly.

My wish is to restore old repositories (and if possible user accounts) from old installation I have stored.

Anything that could lead me into possible solution is very much appreciated!

*This is my first question on stack so please forgive me if it is formed improperly, or is being asked in a wrong section.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [this thread](https://github-com.translate.goog/beginor/docker-gitlab-ce/issues/6?_x_tr_sl=zh-CN&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc), try and check if locales/tzdata are missing:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq locales tzdata && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

This is similar to [`postgres-ai/custom-images` issues/4](https://gitlab.com/postgres-ai/custom-images/-/issues/4), which means, if it works at runtime, you might have to build your own GitLab image, with:

```
RUN apt-get install -yqq locales locales-all tzdata && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I have tried to do exactly that, build my own GitLab image using [docs/Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/build/build_package.md) with sources from **tag/12.4.0+ce.0**, I've modified `omnibus-gitlab/docker/Dockerfile` to include the **RUN** line you suggested, but I am not so well-versed in such complex docker builds and I have failed at last step `bundle exec rake build:project`, first it reminded me of uncommited changes, then after commiting those it fails to build with message: `fatal: no tag exactly matches '1b8.. rest of hash ..165'`

Comment: @ponki Why your Dockerfile  woudl call an `exec rake` command?

Comment: It does not, maybe I wasn't clear enough, it is the last step of building gitlab as per link I included in my previous comment, it is done from within build image container shell `docker -run (...) -it (...) bash`, unless there is another way to build a custom gitlab image, I am certain that I do something wrong along the way, just tried it again and failed at the same step

Comment: @ponki The idea is to start with a `Dockerfile` using `FROM an-existing-GitLab-tag`, and add ony the additional packages relative to locale. Not to rebuild anything from GitLab.

Comment: you opened my eyes there, I overcomplicated that process when It was a simple job as you stated, thank you very much, the final solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

Solution marked as an **accepted answer** worked beautifully, for further readers and to summarize, what was the final solution:

I have created an image using Dockerfile based on specific version of official gitlab-ce docker image and included locales packages.

Dockerfile in question:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.4.0-ce.0

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update

# Install common software to aquire add-apt-repository command
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update

# Add universe repository to get access to locales package
RUN add-apt-repository universe

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update

# Install missing locales & generate en_US one
RUN apt-get -y install -yqq locales locales-all tzdata && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

# Continue with official gitlab-ce commands from their image...
# Wrapper to handle signal, trigger runit and reconfigure GitLab
CMD ["/assets/wrapper"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=60s --timeout=30s --retries=5 \
CMD /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-healthcheck --fail --max-time 10
```

Then it was just simple

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

If it is bloated, or something is not necessary feel free to correct me, otherwise it is what worked for me in the end.

Thanks once again to @Vonc for providing me with what lead to the final solution!